# How can I use QTextEdit with remote images?

Tags: image, qt, qtextedit

I'm trying to implement a simple text editor that among other things should be able to show images available through http in a html formatted text - img tags.

However, I don't really know how to go about implementing this and don't even know if that is supported in the first place.

Does QTextEdit support remote images? 
If so, how could I implement that?

Comment: What you mean by "remote images"? If they are available throught file system - then they should be loaded. If they are available throught "http" you need to download them manually.

Comment: That's correct, images available through http. So no real support of http images after all? Is it standard practice to simply download to a temp file and use file://?

Comment: @coder: getting image via http to desktop application is: 1. weird, 2. much more complicated than you may think ;)

Comment: Use any of available web views to display such content.

Comment: @Saz, using a web view sounds more cumbersome than having to download the images to be honest. Am I being too harsh here? Do you think there are enough benefits for the long run to move the editor into a web view?

Comment: @MichałWalenciak, I don't know what people are doing out there but you might be right.